# Styled Components: props for hover

Tags: styled-components

I want to apply a `&:hover` only when a prop is passed - in this situacion: `animated`

```
const AnimationContainer = styled.div`
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;

  &:hover { // apply hover only when $(props.animated) is paased
     position: fixed;
     transform: translate(0%, -30%);
     transition: 0.3s ease-out;
   }
`;
```

Does anyone have a suggestion how to do it? 
I guess it would be possible to apply the styling for every property just starting with `.. :$(props => props.animated ? ..)`, but is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yup! Like this:

```
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components'

const AnimationContainer = styled.div`
  transform: translate(0%);
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;

  ${props => props.animated && css`
    &:hover {
      position: fixed;
      transform: translate(0%, -30%);
      transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    }
  `}
`

export default AnimationContainer
```

And then you may use it like this:

```
import AnimationContainer from './path/to/AnimationContainer

// some component here…
  render() {
    return (
      <!-- some JSX element… -->
        <AnimationContainer animated>
          With animation
        </AnimationContainer>
        <AnimationContainer>
          Without animation
        </AnimationContainer>
      <!-- end of some JSX element… -->
    )
  }
```

Learn more about [props](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/basics#passed-props) and [css](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#css) in Styled Components.

Comment: I'm confused. I see how that works if `animated` prop is passed, but what about the `:hover` pseudo-class? To me, the above won't do anything when hovering over the div.

Comment: @skube You're right, I forgot about that, edited to fix. The css is just inserted in the outer one, so you can just add the &:hover selector as you normally would.