# How do you do conditional hovering in styled components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I have a component that based on certain props I want the ability to change the background on hover. but based on other props, hover should do nothing. is this possible?

```
export const Container = styled.div`

    &:hover {
        background: ${({ shouldHover }) => shouldHover ? 'red' : '' };
    }
`
```

however this does not work. any suggestions how this can be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styled Components: props for hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47635991/styled-components-props-for-hover)

Answer (score 11):

This will work:

```
export const Container = styled.div`
    ${ props => props.shouldHover 
        ? '&:hover { background: red }' 
        : ''
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like the following, that may help:

```
import { css, styled } from 'styled-components'

styled.div`
   ${props => props.shouldHover && css`
      &:hover {
        background: 'red';
      }
   `}
`
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import styled from "styled-components";
const Container = styled.div`
  & > h2 {
    &:hover {
      background: ${props => (props.shouldHover ? "red" : "none")};
    }
  }
`;
function App({ shouldHover }) {
  return (
    <Container shouldHover>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic shappen!</h2>
    </Container>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App shouldHover />, rootElement);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/8yvjyv3q4j)

Answer (score -1):

You can make the background conditional based on what props you pass down. Below is an example where the div changes based on multiple different conditions.

```
const Container = styled.div`
  background: blue;

  &:hover {
    background: ${props => props.shouldHoverRed 
      ? 'red'
      : props.shouldHoverGreen
      ? 'green'
      : props.shouldHoverOrange
      ? 'orange'
      : 'blue'
    };
  }
`
```

default is blue and depending on the prop passed it will render different colors for the background on hover.

Comment: IMO nested ternaries like that should be avoided if possible, it's pretty bad when it comes to readability.

Comment: where do you set shouldHoverRed, shouldHoverGreen, shouldHoverOrange ??!